# Workbook_BeforeSave not triggering some events

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with Workbook_BeforeSave where the event is called, but most of the code doesn't do anything.

What I want to do is password protect some sheets, hide another sheet and activate a third. Strangely, some items such as debug.print and MsgBox within the sub work. I also have sheets activated from within Workbook_Open, but most of the code that I try to execute within the Workbook_BeforeSave sub simply does not fire. Here's the code that I am trying to run:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If AdministratorAccess Then     '   A boolean that is marked true when admin logs in
        If MsgBox("For security, sheets must be locked and Admin logged out before saving. " & _
            "Do you want to Save the workbook?", _
                vbYesNo, "Changes not saved") = 6 Then
            Call protectReadiness   '   A sub that protects the 'Project Readiness' sheet
            Call protectViewer      '   A sub that protects the 'Project viewer' sheet
            Call veryHideUsers      '   A sub that xlVeryHides the 'Users' sheet
            Sheets("Project viewer").Activate
            MsgBox ("To continue editing as Admin, simply log back in.")
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Else
        Call protectReadiness   '   A sub that protects the 'Project Readiness' sheet
        Call protectViewer      '   A sub that protects the 'Project viewer' sheet
        Call veryHideUsers      '   A sub that xlVeryHides the 'Users' sheet
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In the above code snippet, the calls for 'protectReadiness' and Sheets("Project viewer").activate simply do not run. When I add them to the immediate window, they work fine. Also the MsgBox activates and displays correctly.

I've spent a couple of hours looking for a solution online and can't find anything. I've tried removing everything from the sub except for the sheet.activate, and found that it does nothing. I've tried moving the helper methods protect- and veryhide- to the ThisWorkbook section of the VBA editor. I'm really at a loss for what to do.

Does anyone have an idea on what I might be doing wrong, or what could be causing this strange behavior? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the `Sheets("Project viewer").activate` line is actually running?

Comment: What's your setting under *Tools >> Options >> General >> Error Trapping* ?

Comment: Hi Tim, when I set break points over that line and the ones that follow and save the sheet, I can see the break enter the Workbook_BeforeSave sub and step over those lines. It doesn't throw any errors so I assume that means it runs. Is this what you mean? 

I also have 'Break on Unhandled Errors' set in the Error Trapping settings.

Comment: Try "break in class module" and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately no, that didn't change anything. The execution still steps over those methods throwing no errors, but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: OK, well...   Your code works fine for me (with stubs in place of whatever is in the subroutines called from the Save event).  I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Tim. I have a feeling that this might be caused by some settings on my administrated network. It is unfortunate for me but at least I can stop pulling my hair out now.